# Identifying the threads accessing a static block of code?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a static function like:

```
public static void foo()
{
    //code follows
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    //code follows
}
```

and multiple threads are calling this function concurrently. I have set the names of threads using

```
Thread.setName(String)
```

When i execute the code, the print statement will print the name of only one thread. How can i identify the names of all the threads currently executing the foo() function?

**EDIT:**

```
public class FooThread extends Thread
{
public FooThread(String name)
{
this.setName(name);
}
@Override public void run()
{
//do something
//do something
Main.foo();

}
}


//Main Class
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
for(int i=0;i<6;++i)
{
new FooThread("Thread"+i).start();
}
}

public static void foo()
{
//do something 
while(true)
{
//do something
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

}
}
```

Comment: `"How can i identify the names of all the threads currently executing the foo() function?`" -- You already are doing this. If the println is only showing one thread, then only one thread is calling that code. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: That means that you only called the function once.

Comment: Lets say i have an infinite while loop inside foo and any thread calling it gets stuck inside the foo() block. After some time more than one threads will be inside it. I am going to edit my question.

Comment: Are sure you have assigned a different name to each of your threads? try to print the thread id too `Thread#getId()`, If yes then you might have only one threa calling `foo()` as Hovercraft said.

Answer (score 4):

You're already showing the name of the Thread that is calling your code. Code that proves this:

```
public class Foo2 {
   public static synchronized void foo() {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int maxCount = 10;
      for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++) {
         Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               foo();
            }
         });
         thread.setName("Thread " + i);
         thread.start();
         long sleepTime = 1000;;
         try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }
   }
}
```

Return:

```
Thread 0
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 3
Thread 4
Thread 5
Thread 6
Thread 7
Thread 8
Thread 9
```

Your problem lies in code not shown.

- Either your method is being called by one and only one thread, or
- Or you're giving all your threads the same name.

Again, for a complete solution as to what is actually wrong with your current set up, create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) similar to what I've posted above. For all we know you could be calling `run()` on your Threads, and until we can see *and reproduce* your problem, I don't think that we'll be able to fully understand it.

---

**EDIT**
Regarding your SSCCE: Compare the results of the two methods below, foo1() and foo2()

```
class FooThread extends Thread {

   public FooThread(String name) {
      this.setName(name);
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      // do something
      // do something

      Main.foo1();  // !! Swap comments
      // Main.foo2(); // !! Swap comments
   }
}

// Main Class
public class Main {
   private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 4;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
         new FooThread("Thread" + i).start();
      }
   }

   public static void foo1() {
      // do something
      while (true) {
         // do something
         synchronized (Main.class) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
         }
         try {
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

      }
   }

   public static void foo2() {
      while (true) {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
   }
}
```

If your while loop isn't so tight, but yields the CPU with say a short Thread.sleep, you'll see more of the different threads sharing foo in closer proximity.

But again, your code also proves that your Thread names **are8* being displayed, but that you're only seeing one name likely because that thread is hogging the CPU.

Comment: I have added the SSCCE.

Comment: @Madeyedexter: you're `while (true)` is not allowing other threads to run. Only one thread may have access to foo for a while.

Comment: @Madeyedexter: is foo synchronized?

Comment: I see that Main.foo() can be called by other threads after they are created. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Madeyedexter: again, is there any synchronization going on? Your problem is likely to be one of concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to get all the Thread stacks and look for all the threads in the `foo()`  This has the benefit of no overhead or extra code, except to capture the information you want.

BTW: Can you make it clearer why do you need this information as I suspect there is a better way to do what you really want?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the count of threads, use a thread-safe counter to store number of threads. Increase the counter when foo() begins, and decrease the counter when foo() exits.

If you need to get the names, use a hash set (or list if there are duplicates of thread names) to store the names: Add the name when foo() begins, and remove the name when foo() exits. Make sure the access to hash set is thread safe. You also need another method to print out the content of the hash set, so you can call it any time to see what are the name of threads executing foo().

Comment: This does not answer his question.

Comment: Idea is the same for names.

Comment: Not even close. This only counts the number of times foo is called, and has no indication of unique thread whatsoever.

Comment: If you are considering threads with the same name non-unique, then HashSet is the right way to go. Idea is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the name into a list when the method starts (in a synchronized block) and remove it at the end again.

```
List allTheNames = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

public void foo() {
    allTheNames.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    // now allTheNames contains all the names of all threads currently in this method.
    System.out.println(allTheNames.toString());
    allTheNames.remove(Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Of course, if you change the name of the thread in the meantime that wont work, but why would you do so?

You could also store the `Thread` itself if you need other informations that the name.